# Ubuntu Installation troubles

Tags: software-installation

I'm having trouble downloading and installing Ubuntu on my computer. I want to do either a native install or a virtual machine. After I download Ubuntu from the site and try to open the .iso file, it gives a message saying "no mountable file systems". How do I fix this?

There are instructions on how to install Ubuntu but they start from the installation menu screen. I am having difficulty even getting to that part. Please Help!!!

Is there any way to install Ubuntu from the download? It almost seems to me that I need to burn that file to a CD and then use the CD to install it. But that can't be the way. Anything helps. Thanks!

Comment: Are you doing a native install or a virtual machine install? If you are doing a native install, then you DO need to burn it to a CD and install from that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install Ubuntu you cannot install it just from opening .iso file. It needs to be burned on the disc. If you don't have a DVD-ROM in your computer or for some other reason cannot use discs you may use USB, as well.
See the link:
[How to create a bootable USB
stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

If you want to use Ubuntu via Virtual machine use VirtualBox software. See the links for easy and nice tutorials:

[wikihow.com / Install-Ubuntu-on-VirtualBox](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Ubuntu-on-VirtualBox)

[Installing Ubuntu inside Windows using VirtualBox](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/virtualbox)